# I have a sample question for Update query and DB index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, sql-update

I have a sample query for Update.

```
update appianData.IC_MST_CodeDateData
    left join appianData.IC_MST_Velocity
    on IC_MST_CodeDateData.whse = IC_MST_Velocity.whse and IC_MST_CodeDateData.article = IC_MST_Velocity.article
    set IC_MST_CodeDateData.velocity = IC_MST_Velocity.velocity;
```

Sometimes this query will get times out and sometimes it runs only in 3 seconds, totally randomly.

So as I check the index for the table **IC_MST_CodeDateData** and **IC_MST_Velocity**, the IC_MST_CodeDateData has the composite index (Column whse+ Column article), and IC_MST_Velocity has Two separate indexes (Column whse and Column article).

Is that the reason cause this query sometimes times-out and sometimes finished in 3 seconds?

Comment: Why is it `LEFT`?

Comment: @RickJames Because it is left join?

Comment: This implies that when the row from `appianData` is missing, you will set velocity to NULL.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The search is performed on the table `IC_MST_Velocity` using the columns `whse` and `article`. But:

- With two separate indexes MySQL will perform a *wide* Index Range Scan, using one index, and filtering columns out. Not optimal for update.
- With a composite index, MySQL will perform a *narrow* Index Range Scan on the composite index. Much faster for update, since it needs to walk a lot less rows.

Therefore, you should try creating the index:

```
create index ix1 on IC_MST_Velocity (whse, article);
```

If you really want more update performance you an even include the retrieved columns in it to create what's called a *covering index*. For example:

```
create index ix1 on IC_MST_Velocity (whse, article, velocity);
```

Comment: so I can keep the index for CODEDATEDATA table and modify index on velocity table right?

Comment: Yes. You can also keep all indexes, if you want. As a rule of thumb try not to have more than 10 indexes per table.

Comment: So is this is the reason why this query sometimes run 3 seconds to finished and sometimes timeout?   The data is fine as I check.

Comment: I can't be sure about that. The absence of the composite index surely adds stress on the database engine, and under different load the response time could vary wildly.